# Back button not working and error 404 on refresh

Tags: vue.js, netlify

I have hosted my vue application on netlify. I have 2 questions: 
1) When i press a back button on browser or on mobile, it is not going back instead it reloads the same/current page.

2) When i reload manually it gives me this error => " Page Not Found
Looks like you've followed a broken link or entered a URL that doesn't exist on this site."

My vue router is in 'history' mode right now.

i expect that the back button should work properly and on manual refresh, it should load the same page where user is right now.

Answer (score 0):

1) Maybe is a problem of your code, add details if it doesn't continue to work

2) You have to write a rewrite rule: [Rewrites and proxying](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/#rewrites-and-proxying)

Read "HISTORY PUSHSTATE AND SINGLE PAGE APPS", you have to create a file "_redirects" under the public directory and write in

`/*    /index.html   200`

Comment: i dont want to redirect to a particular page but instead it should redirect to that current page on which the user will refresh the page

Comment: This is a redirect for server side. Your vue application is an SPA, it uses a client side router: first of all, your server request have to go to index.html, then vue-router go to your actual page based on the real link.